# “Everything you want (to do)” vs “All you want (to do)”

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, determiners, meaning

On a language-exchange app I use, a non-native speaker said (emphasis mine):

> When you are absolutely sick and tired of exams and **everything** you want is to listen to music

One person corrected *everything* to *all,* and the non-native asked why they made the change. I’ve tried googling the answer for a while now, and read up a little on pronouns and determiners, but I still don’t know how to explain it.

So my question is: How do you explain why you’re supposed to use *all* instead of *everything* here?

Answer (score 1):

Because in this context, **everything** and **all** are not synonymous. In certain situations, they can mean the same the thing, more or less. For instance:

> ***He wanted to experience everything the city had to offer.***

means the same thing as

> ***He wanted to experience all the city had to offer.***

However, in the case of:

> ***All you want to do is listen to music...***

then **all** serves to *exclude everything else from consideration*. In other words, you don't want to do anything else **except** listen to music. That's **all** you want to do.

So that's the distinction.

---